# C - Onde estou errando? [Error] Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um código que relacione a quantidade de clientes, tipo de combustível que cada um abasteceu e me mostre a porcentagem de clientes que abasteceram com cada combustível. É algo bem simples, já que estou iniciando.

Meu código está assim:

```
int main() {

    int c, g, a;
    float Pg, Pa;
    
    printf ("Registro de fim do dia\n");
    
    printf ("\nQuantidade total de clientes hoje: ");
    scanf ("%d", &c);
    printf ("Quantos abasteceram com gasolina: ");
    scanf ("%d", &g);
    printf ("Quantos abasteceram com alcool: ");
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    
    Pg = (100*g) /c;
    Pa = (100*a) /c;
    
    Printf ("\n%.2f dos clientes abasteceram com gasolina\n", Pg);
    Printf ("%.2f dos clientes abasteceram com alcool", Pa);


    return 0;
}
```

Não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro exatamente no código. O erro mostrado no Registro é:

> [Error] Id returned 1 exit status.

Ao clicar nesse erro, sou enviado ao `Makefile.win` com essa linha selecionada: `$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)`.

Comment: A linguagem C é case sensitive, o nome da função é `printf` e não `Printf`. Note que aqui: `Pg = (100*g) /c;` você está fazendo operações com inteiros e apenas na atribuição é que ocorre a conversão para `float`, para fazer a operação em ponto flutuante faça: `Pg = (float)(100*g) / c;` que aí a divisão será feita em ponto flutuante. Idem para o cálculo de `Pa`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado <3